# instance class from swc inside a movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swc

i'm trying to use compiled assets and code from a swc.
Inside a new fla I select the swc to be included when exporting.
When create the instance in the timeline of the code works and I can see assets that are inside the swc and trace a propertie from the same object.
The problem is only when doing the same inside a movieclip, can't reach the assets (movieclip) but I can still trace properties from the class.

I've uploaded the working files:
master.fla is the one that creates the swc.
template.fla is where I test the swc.

[files](http://www.complexresponse.com/out/test_swc.zip) (This are cs4 .fla + .swc + .as)

**EDIT:**
How to reproduce the problem I had:

.1 create a new master.fla and make it compile a swc.

.2 In master.fla timeline create a Textfield, give it the instance name of "tfield" and make a MovieClip from it.

.3 Create a TextBox.as class and define a public variable "tfield" (this will pickup the TextField asset you have inside your movie).

.4 In library link the newly created MovieClip to the TextBox class.

.5 Export and you should be seeing a instance of the TextBox class.

using the swc:

.1 Create a new fla and make it use the master.swc as source

.2 open first frame in timeline and write the following code:

```
var tf : TextBox = new TextBox();
addChild(tf)
```

This should work as expected, creating a instance of the TextBox and you should see the TextField inside.

.3 comment the previous code and write the same code but this time inside a MovieClip and drop it to the timeline. Although the code works the "tfield" is not accessible. Nor you can see it.

**SOLUTION:** As pointed out by Daniel just give a linkage id to the MovieClip that contains the code (DON'T give the TextBox class id, just make it create a new class like "lalala").

Thank you Daniel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a linkage id to tf in template

Comment: thank you very much Daniel. That was it! I was reading back my question and I did explain myself like ass. I'll update my question hoping this makes more sense for others if they find themselves in same situation. Then, again, thank you sir!

Comment: you can also add `var b:TextBox` to the main timeline. The other thing you can do is add a linkage ID to only one movieClip that has reference: `var ref:TextBox`  it looks like the Flash compiler is having a problem creating the class. I only use the flex compiler and haven't seen this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

[fixed](http://www0z0k.narod.ru/test_swc_fixed.zip)
added `TextField` initialization to `TextBox.as` (to avoid null reference when tracing `tfield.text`) and renamed `tf: TextBox` to `tb:TextBox` to make name different from `tf` on the stage

Comment: hi www0z0k, thanks for the time, I think I was not able to explain myself clear. The problem is not in the template when instantiate the TextBox object that gets from the swc. I can trace the key variable, so the class is being executed. The problem is about the tfield TextField that doesn't appear when I instantiate from within a movieCLip () from the main timeline it works nicely. This is diving my head around =)

Comment: @ dome - may i ask you to update the files? i added the TextBox (and tfield was visible) in the first frame of tf instance on stage

Comment: sorry for my lame explanation, I've updated the post, now it should be easier to understand the problem I was having. In your update you where creating a new TextField instance, but it should be pickup the one it was inside the MovieClip.